# Activating/Deactivating GameObject Not Working

Tags: button, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I can't seem to get my button to activate gameobject. At the moment, I have the gameobject deactivating in the scene, but my button doesn't activate the gameobject. What am I'm missing in my coding? The script is currently not attach to the gameobject.

```
#pragma strict

 public var myObject :GameObject;

     if (GUI.Button(new Rect(1120,930,100,50),"3D OBJECT"))

     {
        myObject.SetActive(true);
     }
```

Comment: Which gameObject is the script attached to?

Answer (score 1):

I dont understand your question well but,
first of all if you want to use `GUI` you must do it in [OnGUI](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnGUI.html) function.

Like:

```
function OnGUI () {
     if (GUI.Button(new Rect(1120,930,100,50),"3D OBJECT"))
     {
        myObject.SetActive(true);
     }
}
```

By the way i strongly recommend you that: Use [Unity UI](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui) for GUI purposes.

Comment: Sorry about that, I have the function OnGUI in my code already.  I just copy and paste incorrectly.

Comment: Yes, I am currently using Unity UI for activating and deactivating the gameobject.  But I'm force to use scripting to activate / deactivate gameobject instead.